# Discord.js reaction channel delete with error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I click on the reaction, another message is sent and after 5 seconds the channel is deleted. The problem is that when it gets deleted, I get an error and crash the bot

```
  reactCreateMessage(reaction, user);
  reactCloseTickets(reaction, user);
  reactDeleteTickets(reaction, user);
});
async function reactDeleteTickets(reaction, user) {
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (reaction.message.channel.parentID != config.TICKETS.CATEGORY) return;
  let nomeChannel = reaction.message.channel.name;
  if (!nomeChannel.includes("closed-")) return;
  nomeChannel = nomeChannel.replace("ticket-closed-", "");
  if (isNaN(nomeChannel)) return;
  if (reaction.emoji.name === config.REACTIONS.DELETE_TICKET) {
    updateTicketDelete("ticket", "id_stato", "deleted", "id_ticket", nomeChannel, "id_stato", "closed");
    var mex = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(messagcfg.message_on_close_ticket.color)
      .setTitle("TICKET ELIMINATO")
      .setDescription("Questo ticket verrà eliminato tra 5 secondi... ");
    reaction.message.reactions.removeAll();
    reaction.message.channel.send(mex).then(messaggio => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        messaggio.channel.delete();
      }, 5000);
    })
    return;
  }
```

**This is the error:**

```
     throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
           ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
   at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\kikib\Documents\EndlessTicketsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
   at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\kikib\Documents\EndlessTicketsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
 method: 'put',
 path: '/channels/806287992477843508/permissions/738036146151358504',
 code: 10003,
 httpStatus: 404
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: To confirm, did the channel actually delete?

Comment: Yes @Dinty the channel is actually deleted